# Stop removing zero from floats number (3.0 to 3 ) automatically in mysql

Tags: mysql

Data type is float, When I add a number with zero ex- 7.0 it turns into 7. How to stop this

Comment: Why? `7.0` and `7` are exactly the same number.

Comment: And MySQL isn't rounding in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The float data type stores approximate values. See the following for a description.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

For exact numbers use decimal.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html